# prove that an entire function is bounded

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be a entire function and suppose that $\lim\limits_{z\rightarrow\infty}f(z)=0$. Does it impliy that $f$ is bounded? If so, how can I prove it?

Answer (score 1):

From the definition of a limit we know there is some $R>0$ such that $|f(z)|<1$ when $|z|> R$. Also, the set $A:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z|\leq R\}$ is compact, and so $|f|$ is bounded on $A$, because it is a continuous function defined on a compact set.

So $f$ is bounded in both $A$ and $\mathbb{C}\setminus A$, thus it is bounded in all $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

The neighborhoods of $\infty$ on the Riemann sphere are the exteriors of closed disks.

To say that $\lim_{z\to\infty}f(z)=0$ is to say that $\forall \varepsilon>0,$ $\exists N$ such that $\mid z\mid>N$ implies $\mid f(z)\mid <\varepsilon$.  But $\mid z \mid \leq N$ is compact, so $f$ is bounded on this region too, and so bounded on $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 0):

The statement that $\lim_{z \to \infty} f(z) = 0$ implies that $f$ is bounded in the set $\{z: |z| > r\}$ for some $r > 0$.  On the other hand, $\{z: |z| \le r\}$ is a compact set, on which any continuous function must be bounded.